# Error deploying Nuxt website with dynamic routes to firebase hosting

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

In my website I have dynamic routes that will be made whenever a client fills in a form. A specific project page is made for that client. Therefore I have the following structure

```
pages
-project
--_id.vue
```

When I was finished building the website I wanted to upload the website to Firebase hosting, but soon I found out that new links like "/project/5b97b1d5-82f5-488c-9ac4-009d2b322b73" gave an error saying:

Error: Page not found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Now I've been reading several posts and solutions, but none of them worked. A few of the solutions I found were:

1. deploy using firebase functions
2. use `generate:{routes:{some code}}` in `nuxt.config.js`

While trying these solutions I came accross the following problems:

**1. deploy using firebase functions**
For this solution I followed the steps described in this [article](https://medium.com/@sirofjelly/deploying-a-nuxt-ssr-server-side-rendering-app-to-google-firebase-5d90117167db).

Additionally to this article I had to install firebase-functions inside /functions folder and I had to add `"engines": {"node": "16"},"type": "commonjs",` to /functions/package.json.

when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` I get the error below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipxIq.png)
when I run `firebase deploy --only functions --debug` I get the error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYlLo.png)

I'm not sure how to fix this error. It seems like it something to do with ES5.

**2. use `generate:{routes:{some code}}` in `nuxt.config.js`**
Using this method, I would need to use axios to generate some urls. However, I thinks this is not going to work if there will be new project id's made after generating. In that case this solution won't work. Is there another way to use it?

**What are my expectations?**
To have dynamic project id's that will work even after a new one has been made after generating.

Any help would be appreciated!